# Numpad On External KB

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I use an external apple keyboard with a numeric pad but its number keys don't produce numbers, in fact they produce nothing. The plus, hyphen, enter buttons do work even `0x47 keypad-numlock` but it does not toggle on the numeric buttons. This is my keyboard:

```
  Product ID:   0x0221
  Vendor ID:    0x05ac  (Apple Inc.)
```

Please advise.

Comment: What is the model number as printed on the bottom of the keyboard itself? It should start with an 'A'. My keyboard is A1243. Have you tested this keyboard on another computer?

Comment: It is A1243 as well. I am using Karabiner EventViewer to catch keyboard events and it shows nothing when e.g. now I press '5' on the Numeric keyboard. But something is definitely happening because when I press it the last character is highlighted and if I press it twice this entire paragraph is highlighted (selected).

Answer (score 1):

Num Keys did not work because I had Mouse Keys enabled.

To disable it:

Open  Apple menu and choose “System Preferences”, then go to “Accessibility”
Select “Mouse & Trackpad” and untick the option called “Enable Mouse Keys”

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting the clear key on the keyboard, or holding shift and clicking the clear key that should do it.

Source:
http://osxdaily.com/2014/12/01/number-keys-not-working-mac-keyboard-fix/